# views / activities in android

Tags: android

I want to implement a design as visible in the following picture:

[image]

In the main you can see the small views. When you click one it maximizes to full sceen.

How do I implement this in Android?

Answer (score 0):

There are multitude of ways you can implement this.

one way is to have the 4 contents as `imageButton` and when you click on it , it open a new `activity` which shows the content in fullscreen.

or you can use a `tableLayout` instead of `imageButton`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with images on the main screen, within say a gallery or grid [view](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html), that when each is touched, [opens a new activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) based on the image touched.

Links are to google android developers pages, showing information on the available view types and how to open an activity.